# HLSL Shader: Computation outside of vertex shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl

I'm writing a shader in HLSL with Unity/Shaderlab. I need to be able to control this shader from an outside script, by defining some points in space. I do so using the `keyword` uniform :

```
uniform float3 _WandPosition;
uniform float3 _WandNormal;
```

As the position is given in Unity-space, I need to transform this into Object-space :

```
Varyings vert(Attributes IN)
{
    Varyings OUT;

    // ... Some other calculations

    OUT.wandPositionOS = TransformWorldToObject(_WandPosition);
    OUT.wandNormalOS = TransformWorldToObjectDir(_WandNormal);
    return OUT;
}
```

Saving the result in a texture (which is not ideal...):

```
struct Varyings
{
    // ...
    float3 wandPositionOS : TEXCOORD3; // NOT OPTIMIZED
    float3 wandNormalOS : TEXCOORD4; // NOT OPTIMIZED
};
```

That means that this operations are made for each vertex, for each frame. I'd like to do it once for all the vertex, is it possible ?
Even more ideally, is it possible to do it only when the value is updated ?

Thanks !

Comment: How do you set `_WandPosition` and `_WandNormal`? Couldn't you already there set the transformed values using the according [`transform.worldToLocalMatrix`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localToWorldMatrix.html) ... Not that much into shaders tbh

Comment: I simply use : `Shader.SetGlobalVector("_WandPosition", position);`. Not sure but it may be a simple solution. I'll do some tests ! Thanks :)

Comment: yeah i reckon you would do a calculation like that "outside", @Eyap

Comment: Well I think it depends here whether it is better in performance to calculate that once for all instances of that shader or calculate it in each instance ...

Comment: @derHugo Well, after some tests it's working fine when using a scale of (1, 1, 1). I still have some problems when scale is not uniform. Apart from that, I didn't see any FPS changes on PC by using this instead of what I had described... On mobile not using TEXCOORD may still be interesting, I will test that tomorrow.